# Git Extensions executable disappears

Tags: git, windows-10, git-extensions

I have recently installed both Git Extensions 3.4.3 and git-2.30.1 64bit windows on Windows 10.  Once installed, after a short amount of time, I will be presented with this IO error:

[image]

At this point, Git Extensions crashes and the executable has disappeared from program files.  Additionally, my Git version has seemingly reverted back to version 2.7:

[image]

To troubleshoot the issue I completely uninstalled git extensions and git (removing git from path as well) and reinstalled but the issue persists and within a short time will occur all over again.

Comment: Take a look at the logs of your antivirus. Did it delete the file? Do you use a VM?

Comment: Physical PC and not seeing anything from my anti-virus logs that would suggest any thread protection changes to the installed software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was due to Microsoft Software Center policies established by my organization.